# Package compatibility

Tags: rpm, redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-linux

I have a home server running Oracle Linux 6, which is very similar to Red Hat and runs a RHEL compatible kernel.  My question is, to what extent would packages originally made for other rpm-based distos (eg. Fedora) be compatible with OL6?  Also, the repository for OL6 is not large (I'm used to Debian), would it be possible to use a RHEL or Fedora repo as a secondary with OL6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with RHEL you have to have a paid subscription in order to download packages from their repos. Since you are using OL6, your best bet is to install [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), its an extended compatible package addon that works with RHEL,OL,and CentOS. I would avoid adding Fedora built repos as those are not compatible with enterprise OSes.